# Unhidde non consecutive columns

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script

I would like to unhide non consecutive columns that were previously hidden.

I've got a list of hidden columns in hideColumns variable. The function showColumn seems to have an input with integers for the number of the column.

So, I've tried that and it's not working:

```
function myfunction2 () {

 //list of columns that I want to hide/unhide
  const hideColumns = [1,3,7,15];

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
 
   for (let i = 1; i <= hideColumns.length; i++) {
    sheet.showColumns(hideColumns[i]);}}
```

I've got that error message

Exception: The parameters (null) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.showColumns. myfunction2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- The first index of the array is 0. But, in your script, 1 to the length of the array is used as the index. In this case, at the last loop, the value `hideColumns[i]` is `undefined`. By this, such an error occurs.

In order to remove this issue, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script 1:

In this modification, your showing script is modified.

```js
function myfunction2() {
  //list of columns that I want to hide/unhide
  const hideColumns = [1, 3, 7, 15];

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  for (let i = 0; i < hideColumns.length; i++) {
    sheet.showColumns(hideColumns[i]);
  }
}
```

#### Modified script 2:

In this modification, for-of is used.

```js
function myfunction2() {
  //list of columns that I want to hide/unhide
  const hideColumns = [1, 3, 7, 15];

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  for (const v of hideColumns) {
    sheet.showColumns(v);
  }
}
```

#### Modified script 3:

In this modification, forEach is used.

```js
function myfunction2() {
  //list of columns that I want to hide/unhide
  const hideColumns = [1, 3, 7, 15];

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  hideColumns.forEach(e => sheet.showColumns(e));
}
```

- In this modification, when `hideColumns.forEach(e => sheet.showColumns(e));` is modified to `sheet.showColumns(1, sheet.getMaxColumns());`, all columns are shown without using a loop.

#### References:

- [Array() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array)
- [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)